# Can't click anywhere on my website from iPhone

Tags: html, ios, css, iphone

I have one problem with my web site, if i open the website from any android device, everything is fine and the page work normal. But if i open the web site from my iPhone or any other iPhone (didn't try with other ios devices) i see the webpage, but i can't click anywhere. Can't click on links, button, input fields, images, can't select text or any other content in the page. It's like the page is one big image and can't do nothing there. I try with different browsers (safari, mozilla, chrome) from the iPhone and it's all the same. I don't know what to search exactly... If you need HTML or CSS code i can give you, but i have no idea where to start looking/fixing this problem or what cause it.

Comment: maybe you can add a link or screen shot so we can help?

Comment: Can you give me site url?

Comment: http://bgbattles.eu - This is site url, try to open it from iPhone, so you can see what is the problem exactly...